# SQL SUM (DISTINCT ...) on result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below are two tables TBL1 and TBL2

```
TBL1
ID1    Item    Val1     
100    Shirt    10      
101    Shirt    15      
102    Shirt    10      
100    Shirt    10      
100    Shirt    10      
103    Pants    14      

TBL2        

ID2    ID1    Val2
901    100    24
902    101    15
903    102    31
904    100    45
905    100    62
906    103    17
```

Right now I perform on these two table the following query:

```
SELECT TBL1.Item AS Item,
       Count(DISTINCT TBL1.ID1) AS Cpt,
       SUM (TBL1.Val1) AS Tot1,
       SUM (TBL2.Val2) AS Tot2
FROM TBL1, TBL2
WHERE TBL1.ID1 = TBL2.ID2
GROUP BY TBL1.Item
```

The problem here is that `SUM(TBL1.Val1)` will not take into account redundant value ie the same TBL1.ID1. If I use `SUM(DISTINCT TBL1.ID1)`,
some information will not be taken into account. Here for ID1 = 102 it Val1 = 10 won't be used in the `SUM (DISTINCT TBL1.ID1)`.

How do you think I can rewrite that query so that SUM will operate only for distinct ID1? So that the result is the following:

```
Item    Cpt    Tot1    Tot2
Shirt    5      35      177
Pants    1      14      17
```

Comment: Why both MySQL and MS SQL Server tags? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Consider (9*8)+12 vs 9*(8+12)

Comment: How come `Tot1` is `35` for Shirt?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Look at table first. Only distinct records have to be taken. There are dupes.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Which distinct records are taken so that the result is 35?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Someone messed up with edits. If you'd look at previous edits (or even original question), records in `@TBL1` with IDs 100 and 102 had value of 10, not 12...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came with:

```
DECLARE @TBL1 TABLE (
  ID1 INT
  , Item VARCHAR(10)
  , Val1 INT
  );
  
DECLARE @TBL2 TABLE (
  ID2 INT
  , ID1 INT
  , Val2 INT
  );
  
INSERT INTO @TBL1 (ID1, Item, Val1)
VALUES (100, 'Shirt', 10)
  , (101, 'Shirt', 15)
  , (102, 'Shirt', 10)
  , (100, 'Shirt', 10)
  , (100, 'Shirt', 10)
  , (103, 'Pants', 14);
  
INSERT INTO @TBL2 (ID2, ID1, Val2)
VALUES (901, 100, 24)
  , (902, 101, 15)
  , (903, 102, 31)
  , (904, 100, 45)
  , (905, 100, 62)
  , (906, 103, 17);

;WITH Items (ID1, Item, Val1)
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID1, Item, Val1
  FROM @TBL1
  )
, Items2 (Item, Tot1) 
  AS (
  SELECT Item, SUM(Val1)
  FROM Items
  GROUP BY Item
  )
, TBL2 (ID1, Tot2)
  AS (
  SELECT ID1, SUM(Val2)
  FROM @TBL2
  GROUP BY ID1
  )
SELECT T.Item
  , COUNT(T1.ID1) AS Cpt
  , T.Tot1
  , SUM(DISTINCT T2.Tot2)
FROM Items2 AS T
INNER JOIN @TBL1 AS T1
  ON T1.Item = T.Item
INNER JOIN TBL2 AS T2
  ON T2.ID1 = T1.ID1
GROUP BY T.Item, T.Tot1;
```

It's not so elegant, but it does job done. Here's outcome:

```
╔═══════╦═════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Item  ║ Cpt ║ Tot1 ║ Tot2 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬══════╬══════╣
║ Pants ║   1 ║   14 ║   17 ║
║ Shirt ║   5 ║   35 ║  177 ║
╚═══════╩═════╩══════╩══════╝
```

You can run query on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/421149)

#### Update, added query without CTEs:

```
SELECT T.Item
  , COUNT(T1.ID1) AS Cpt
  , T.Tot1
  , SUM(DISTINCT T2.Tot2) AS Tot2
FROM (
  SELECT Item, SUM(Val1) AS Tot1
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID1, Item, Val1 FROM @TBL1) AS X
  GROUP BY X.Item
  ) AS T
INNER JOIN @TBL1 AS T1
  ON T1.Item = T.Item
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID1, SUM(Val2) AS Tot2
  FROM @TBL2
  GROUP BY ID1
  ) AS T2
  ON T2.ID1 = T1.ID1
GROUP BY T.Item, T.Tot1;
```

This can be ran on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/421378) too

#### Update no. 2

Previous query can theorically provide incorrect results if there would be some dupes, when it's running `SUM(DISTINCT T2.Tot2) AS Tot2`. This should work fine ALWAYS, although it needs additional join.

```
SELECT T1.Item
  , T3.Cpt
  , T1.Tot1
  , T2.Tot2
FROM (
  SELECT Item, SUM(Val1) AS Tot1
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID1, Item, Val1 FROM @TBL1) AS X
  GROUP BY X.Item
  ) AS T1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT T1.Item, SUM(Val2) AS Tot2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID1, Item, Val1 FROM @TBL1) AS T1
  INNER JOIN @TBL2 AS T2
    ON T2.ID1 = T1.ID1
  GROUP BY T1.Item
  ) AS T2
  ON T2.Item = T1.Item
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Item, COUNT(*) AS Cpt
  FROM @TBL1
  GROUP BY Item
  ) AS T3
  ON T3.Item = T1.Item;
```

Comment: You've used a syntax that makes it difficult for me to understand. COuld you reformulate it in simple SQL ?  (not necessary to add the table creation part)

Comment: @Michael I could use temporary tables in that case. Or just could use derived tables. Or I could add extra comments if you would like to. What suits you best?

Comment: I'm more of a standard SQL coder ( not too familiar with Oracle, mysql, sql server syntax)... so I'm not too sure about what you mean by temporary / derived tables... If you mean by temporary intermediate tables maybeit'll help me better. (Here as you started with WITH plus a chain with Items, Item2, TBL2....I'm kinda confused ; only the last select is clear to me but I cant link it the the others)

Comment: @MichaelJohnson I've added a more classic query there. Using Common Table Expressions makes it more readable only. There are various examples and explanations on interwebz how CTEs work, it would be a good idea to read these.

Comment: Great. It helps me now. Less obscur. You've resolved my issue.
Thank you very much.

Comment: UPDATE 2 is woah ! It's getting serious. 
I'll check the query on my code to see if I get the result I want then I'll get back here to confirm it's properly working....did not think I had to go so deep to get it right. Thank you again

Comment: @MichaelJohnson Just wondering why did you unaccepted my answer?